# Wrong version of MariaDB shows up after uninstall and install mariadb@version

Tags: macos, mariadb, homebrew

I had MariaDB version 10.3 installed, which I have to downgrade to version `10.1` for compatibility reasons. So I did:

`brew uninstall mariadb`

And then: `mysql -v` which resulted in command not found, as expected.

Then I installed the older version with:

`brew install mariadb@10.1`

And added it to PATH:

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/bin:$PATH"`

However, now I get this weird result where the 10.1 binary shows version 10.3, even in a new shell instance:

```
$ which mysql
/usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/bin/mysql
$ mysql -v
Server version: 10.3.13-MariaDB Homebrew
$ /usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/bin/mysql -v
Server version: 10.3.13-MariaDB Homebrew
$ ls -ltra /usr/local/opt/ | grep maria
lrwxr-xr-x   1 juha.untinen  admin    30 Apr  8 11:02 mariadb@10.1 -> ../Cellar/mariadb@10.1/10.1.38
```

There is probably some leftover file somewhere, but I can't find any such.

What else could I check?

Comment: Have you tried running `mysql -v` in a new shell session?

Comment: Yes. Forgot to mention it.